# MATE on Ubuntu 22.04 / Caja file manager issue: File download window: Search begins when trying to alter the name of a file

Tags: firefox, desktop-environments, mate, download-manager, caja

I am a MATE user, because I need a task bar that lists the opened windows in a multi-screen environment. I have been using MATE for over 10 years on CentOS and recently switched to Ubuntu 22.04. I installed the MATE Desktop for Ubuntu and am experiences issues with the file manager. On my laptop I installed Ubuntu MATE directly, while I installed the regular Ubuntu 22.04 on my workstation and then installed MATE afterwards.

On both machines I have the same issue:

1. I open a browser (Firefox or Chrome) go to a website and try to download a file. Then the file manager opens and asks me where I want to save the file. The preselected location is always /run/user/.... .
2. Then I am choosing a different location, let's say /home/user/.
3. Then I click in the field with the file name and try to change the name of the file. In the moment I type the first letter in this field, a search field below the field for the filename appears that contains the letters that I typed. At the same time, the file manager starts searching for files with the characters that I typed.

It is literally impossible to rename a file that I try to download. It always starts searching for the entered characters instead of editing the filename. I am forced to save the file with whatever name it has and rename it afterwards (e.g. in the terminal).

This was not an issue when I was using MATE for CentOS, but it is a consistent issue under MATE for Ubuntu, which drives me nuts.
Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

[image]